# Custom php code in magento not working / magento block path wrong

Tags: magento2, php, blocks, widget, code

i am new to magento & using magento 2  . I have to run a php code in my cms page . When i check the website i can understand that the theme is **Alothemes Bencher6** . So what i did is

> app/design/frontend/Alothemes/bencher6/Magento_Theme/templates

i create a new folder called `myphp` and file `myphpcode.phtml` insidethis folder .

So

> app/design/frontend/Alothemes/bencher6/Magento_Theme/templates

there is two folder

1. html  (this folder is there previously)
2. myphp (my custom folder )

in `myphpcode.phtml` i write the following code

```
<?php echo 'hiiiiiiiiiiii' ; ?>
```

Now i created a new page in magento and write the following code in content section

```
<block type="core/template" name="myphpcode" template="myphp/myphpcode.phtml" />
```

But for some reason this code is not working . I clear the cache . But still same . Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add This :-**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::myphp/myphpcode.phtml"}}
```

Comment: really thank you friend .  It is working .

Comment: most welcome happy coding.... :)

Comment: let me check...

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/329168/add-a-new-dropdown-attribute-to-product-and-display-on-product-and-check-out-pag